ubuntu hang problem help
I have a question about ubuntu 22.04. My desktop is 13600kf with Nvidia 4070 super graphics card. I installed ubuntu 22.04 on it. Now I found a problem, that is, my computer hangs. The specific phenomenon is that after I click suspend, the screen will turn off after a while, and the fan of the desktop computer will also stop rotating. I think it has entered the suspend state.
Unfortunately, when I click the desktop computer The power button wakes up, and the desktop fan and other devices start to work normally. The light on the monitor is also white (meaning there is information), but after a while it turns yellow (meaning there is no information). During this period, the screen does not change.
How can I troubleshoot or solve this problem? I will use Linux, but I have no idea how to solve this problem. I hope someone can help me. I would be grateful.
I use Google Translate to translate Chinese into English, so the proper nouns may not be accurate. Please forgive me, if you need me to provide more details, please ask

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I advice you don't use suspend. You can try waiting regime.

Thank you for your response. However, my computer and fan are currently running, and I would like them to stop working.

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We appreciate you taking the time to translate Chinese into English! Does this answer your question? How do I know which NVIDIA driver I need?

Thank you, after I installed the driver through the above method, it worked, but I had installed the graphics card driver before.

This question is similar to: How do I know which NVIDIA driver I need?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
